# How to upgrade dnn form and list module without losing data?

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, upgrade

I had installed dnn FormAndList 05.01.01 for one of my clients.Now my client asks me to upgrade to dnn form and list 5.01.03 version.I have searched for update the package of dnn form and list 5.01.03.But could not find upgrade package for the same.

Can you please assist me how to upgrade dnn FormAndList 05.01.01 to dnn FormAndList 05.01.03 without losing data(form and list data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With modules, you just take the INSTALL package for the version you want to upgrade to, and install that.

You don't need an UPGRADE package like you do for the platform itself.

Steps

1. Download the INSTALL package for 5.1.3
2. Upload that ZIP file to the Host/Extensions page

You should always backup your website and database before installing modules or upgrading modules, just to be safe.

You should also upgrade your DNN install to Version 7, and get the latest F&L module release.

Comment: Installing a new version of a module will not overwrite the existing data for the module, unless of course the module is developed incorrectly. The Form and List module is written in a way that upgrades are fine (but it is always best to do a backup just in case something fails).